# Twitter API - iOS

Tags: ios, api, twitter

I am currently creating an iOS app that integrates Twitter in such a way that it loads tweets into a UITableView. Currently I have gotten the tweets to load into the table view but I am having some issues with the names of the tweeters.

I can get the ID of the users. For example `1186989888` is the ID for [DummyCode](http://twitter.com/dummycodetweets)

Is there a way I can get from the ID, `1186989888` and have it return "Dummy Code". Which is [DummyCode](http://twitter.com/dummycodetweets)'s screen name.

Does anyone know if this is possible with the Twitter API and iOS?

Answer (score 2):

The Twitter [`users/lookup`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup) endpoint allows lookup by `user_id`, for up to 100 users at a time.

For a web-friendly view, you can also look up a single user by ID using a `intent/user` URL, e.g.

https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=1186989888

Comment: What's the best way to solely return the screen name or a JSON response that I can parse to get the screen name?

Comment: The `users/lookup` endpoint will be best for that. There's no way around needing OAuth to do it, though.

Comment: I keep getting `Bad Authentication Data, Code:215`

Comment: That indicates you are not providing appropriate OAuth data to the API endpoint.

Comment: Use [`SLRequest`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/making-api-requests-slrequest).